# Passing variable NAME to a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function, variables, pointers

**Language:** Visual C++, MFC

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2005

So I posted a similar question, but I've come to realize that I was asking the wrong question. I'm trying to use a loop to call a function on several different variables, but somewhere along the way, the program is crashing.

Simplified code is below, but I think it's actually easier to just explain it. I have a function that takes in a CString as a parameter. I have several variables I wish to feed to this function, so I put their names into an array, and I'm trying to pass them to the function that way.

***// THE CODE BELOW IS WHAT I HAVE, BUT IT DOES NOT WORK //***

*Header File:*

```
CString m_strTop;
CString m_strLeft;
CString m_strRight;
CString m_strBottom;

CString *var[4];
```

*Source File:*
**Constructor()**

```
CString *var[4] = {
  &m_strTop
, &m_strLeft
, &m_strRight
, &m_strBottom
};
```

*Source File:*
**theFunction()**

```
void myClass::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CSAPrefsSubDlg::DoDataExchange(pDX);

   for(int i = 2001, j = 0; i <= 2004; i++, j++)
   {
       // THE LINE BELOW IS WHERE THINGS GO WONKY, SPECIFICALLY AT &var[j]
       DDX_Text(pDX, i, *var[j]); // 'i' is the ID of the textbox
   }
}
```

**-- What DDX_Text expects --**

```
void AFXAPI DDX_Text(
   CDataExchange* pDX,
   int nIDC,
   CString& value 
);
```

---

So like I said, I just need to feed the function the actual name of the variable. At least I think. What it's actually doing is establishing a connection between a text box in a dialog and the variable where the text box's input will be stored. I'm dereferencing correctly and everything, but I don't think this is the right approach.

Thank you for any help. And to people who answered my previous question, my apologies for misrepresenting the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` is an array of pointers to `CString`.
`var[j]` is a pointer to `CString`.
`&var[j]` is a pointer to pointer to `CString`.

Now you need to pass the `CString` object. So you need:

```
DDX_Text(pDX, i, *var[j]); // dereference a pointer to CString.
```

Consider using `std::vector` instead of the C-array. It would be:

```
std::vector<CString> var(4);
...

DDX_Text(pDX, i, var[j]); // pass a CString object
```

---

I've noted that you're declaring variable `var` once again in the constructor:

```
CString *var[4] = { // this declares new temporary variable, 
                    // it doesn't initialize one from the header file
  &m_strTop
, &m_strLeft
, &m_strRight
, &m_strBottom
};
```

Shouldn't it be? :

```
var[0] = &m_strTop;
var[1] = &m_strLeft;
var[2] = &m_strRight;
var[3] = &m_strBottom;
```

I suppose you need the following:

```
// header file
class myClass
{
  std::vector<CString> var_;
  ...
};

// source file
myClass::myClass() : var_(4)
{
   ...
}

void myClass::theFunction(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CSAPrefsSubDlg::DoDataExchange(pDX);

   for(int i = 2001, j = 0; i <= 2004; i++, j++)
   {
       DDX_Text(pDX, i, var_[j]); // 'i' is the ID of the textbox
   }
}
```

Comment: Shoot, copied and pasted the wrong thing. I have it correctly as *var[j] but it is still not working correctly. It's not the information stored within the variable that I'm interested in, but the actual name of the variable. Do I just need to make an array of CStrings of the variable names?

Comment: What is DDX_Text looking for?  If it's looking for the reference to the CString, then no, otherwise, you'll need to make var be CString[] = {"m_strTop", "m_strLeft", ...};  It's been so long since I used DDX_Text, I don't remember what it takes as it's third parameter

Comment: What is the "name of variable"? In your case `DDX_Text` copies the value of the control(editbox or something similar) to the `CString` or vice versa depending on `CDataExchange::m_bSaveAndValidate` value.

Comment: Hey Mike, check out the very bottom of my first post. I put it in there :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the right thing into DDX_Text.  It's third parameter is a reference to a CString.  You're passing in the address of a pointer.  So you should probably do something like

```
DDX_Test(pDX, i, *var[j]);
```

Comment: Shoot, copied and pasted the wrong thing. I have it correctly as *var[j] but it is still not correct.